# How to say that something is doing two "parallel" actions A and B?

Tags: writing-style, complex-sentences

I have a slight lexical problem - I would like to emphasize that an agent is doing/achieving two "parallel" actions/goals A and B.

My intuitive idea to say this was to use *both*, like in:

> S both As and Bs (*E.g.*: I propose this method as it both solves the problem and requires less efforts...),

however, this doesn't sound right. My next attempt was:

> S does both A and B (*E.g.*: I propose this method as it does both solve the problem and require less efforts...),

which sounds even worse.

I've also tried to come up with some alternatives, for example - changing *both* with *simultaneously*, which alters slightly the meaning, or:

> S not only As, but also Bs (*E.g.*: I propose this method because it not only solves the problem, but also requires less efforts...),

but neither of them has been better.

I feel already that I am overthinking it, thus, I would be very grateful if anybody shares their opinion regarding the above conundrum?

Comment: I think it is better to write it in this way, *" I propose this method as it solves the problem and requires less efforts as well."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, I don't see any problems with ***I propose this method as it both solves the problem and requires less effort***.

It gets the message across nicely and is not excessively verbose.

A quick search on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22both+solves+the+problem+and%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=3yhgVrOlPMWuswHYm5rwBQ#q=%22both+solves+the+problem+and%22&tbm=bks) confirms that this is a normal way of expressing the idea.